# what are inode numbers 1 and 2 used for

Tags: linux

I find that in my ubuntu distribution, the following files are all allocated inode nos 1 :
/dev/pts,   /sys,   /proc,   /sys/kernel/security,  and a few more entries.

Now somewhere I have read that inode# 1 is 'bad blocks inode' and thus the root directory is allocated inode# 2.

My question is :
1) If that be the case why all those directories are allocated this 'bad blocks inode' no

2) why all these files share the same inode no when they are not even links

3) why is / and /sys/fs and /dev/pts/ptmx allocated the same inode no 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inode 1 is the "bad blocks" inode ***on a ext2/3/4 filesystem***. inode counts exist ***per filesystem***. `/dev/pts`, `/sys`, and `/proc` are mounted from ***other filesystems***.

Comment: In particular, since `/dev/pts` et. al. are not real disk-based file systems, the inode numbers *may* be completely meaningless on those file systems, and are only generated to fulfill requirements that every file have one... But you are correct that in the broader sense, inodes 1 and 2 are not guaranteed to have any particular semantic attached to them across all file system types...